# ExMachina "nested" builds

Tags: elixir, ecto

So I'm a new to elixir, but I cannot find information about this and I really don't understand the problem.

Let's say:

```
%Restaurant{} has many %Discount{}
%Discount{} has many %PromoCode{}
```

Factories:

```
def restaurant_factory do
  %Restaurant{ 
     discounts: [ 
        build(:discount)
     ] 
   }
end 

def discount_factory do
   %Discount{
        promo_codes: [
             build(:promo_code)
        ]
    }
 end 

def promo_code_factory do
     %PromoCode{}
end
```

But when I run:

```
test "" do
    r = insert(:restaurant)
end
```

I get:
** (ArgumentError) expected changeset data to be a %Discount struct, got: %PromoCode

So I can't have "nested" builds? Or something else is wrong?

What would it be the proper way to achieve what I want:
Create a Restaurant, create a Discount associated to the Restaurant and create a Promo Code associated to the Discount?

Full error:

```
  1) test load discount by promo code (Restaurants.Domain.LoadDiscountsServiceTest)
     test/services/load_discounts/service_test.exs:42
     ** (ArgumentError) expected changeset data to be a Elixir.Restaurants.Domain.Models.Discount struct, got: %Res
taurants.Domain.Models.PromoCode{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:built, "promo_codes">, code: "XXYY6Z", created_at
: nil, discounts: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :discounts is not loaded>, discounts_id: nil, id: nil, up
dated_at: nil, use_limit: 3}
     stacktrace:
       (ecto) lib/ecto/changeset/relation.ex:190: Ecto.Changeset.Relation.assert_changeset_struct!/2
       (ecto) lib/ecto/changeset/relation.ex:148: Ecto.Changeset.Relation.do_change/4
       (ecto) lib/ecto/changeset/relation.ex:312: Ecto.Changeset.Relation.map_changes/8
       (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:597: anonymous fn/4 in Ecto.Repo.Schema.surface_changes/3
       (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1925: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
       (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:584: Ecto.Repo.Schema.surface_changes/3
       (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:189: Ecto.Repo.Schema.do_insert/4
       (ecto) lib/ecto/association.ex:556: Ecto.Association.Has.on_repo_change/4
       (ecto) lib/ecto/association.ex:338: anonymous fn/7 in Ecto.Association.on_repo_change/6
       (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1925: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
       (ecto) lib/ecto/association.ex:335: Ecto.Association.on_repo_change/6
       (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1925: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
       (ecto) lib/ecto/association.ex:301: Ecto.Association.on_repo_change/3
       (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:708: Ecto.Repo.Schema.process_children/4
       (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:774: anonymous fn/3 in Ecto.Repo.Schema.wrap_in_transaction/6
       (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:576: anonymous fn/3 in Ecto.Adapters.SQL.do_transaction/3
       (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:1283: DBConnection.transaction_run/4
       (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:1207: DBConnection.run_begin/3
       (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:798: DBConnection.transaction/3
       (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:125: Ecto.Repo.Schema.insert!/4
```

I run the test with:

```
iex -S mix test --trace test/services/load_discounts/service_test.exs:42
```

42 being the line that this specific test begins

Comment: Are you using some package for the factory functionality? What? Also, what line of ode does the error points to?

Comment: @mudasobwa Thank you for your interest. I've updated the question with the full error message. It does not point to a specific line in the test file, I run the test with:  iex -S mix test --trace test/services/load_discounts/service_test.exs:42 . 42 being the line that this specific test is declared.

Comment: You can use `build_list(1, :x)` instead of `[build(:x)]`. Useful if you ever want to build more than one, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

My associations were wrong, in %Discount I had:

`has_many(:promo_codes, Discount)`

I should've had: 
`has_many(:promo_codes, PromoCode)`

Embarrassing! So sorry!